# FFmpeg - Apply blur over face

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to blur a portion of a video using FFmpeg (specifically to blur a face).

I have been trying to use a combination of timeline editing and the various bluring filters, but I cannot find a way to blur only a section of the video.

I'm hoping for something like:

```
-vf boxblur=enable='between(t,10,100)':width=20:height=20:x=400:y=200
```

Where `width`/`height` is size of blurred box and `x`/`y` are location of blurred box.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is possible to apply temporal and spatial blurring to a segment/section – assuming the area you want to blur is a static location.

[image: Black lab pup]
<sub>Original black lab pup image.</sub>

## Using a mask image

[image][image]
<sub>Grayscale PNG mask image and resulting blurred image.</sub>

You can make a grayscale mask image to indicate the area to blur. For ease of use it should be the same size as the image or video you want to blur.

Example using [alphamerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphamerge), [avgblur](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#avgblur), and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i mask.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]alphamerge,avgblur=10[alf];[0:v][alf]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart maskedblur.mp4
```

- The white area is where the blur will occur, but this can easily be reversed with the [negate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#negate) filter for instance: `[1:v]negate[mask];[0:v][mask]alphamerge,avgblur=10[alf]...`
- You could use the [geq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq) filter to generate a mask such as a gradient.

## Blur specific area (without a mask)

[image: Black lab pup with blur effect]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,avgblur=10[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart derpdogblur.mp4
```

**Note:** The x and y offset numbers in overlay (`60` and `30` in this example) must match the crop offsets.

What this example does:

1. Crop the copy to be the size of the area to be blurred. In this example: a 200x200 pixel box that is 60 pixels to the right (`x` axis) and 30 pixels down (`y` axis) from the top left corner.
2. Blur the cropped area.
3. Overlay the blurred area using the same `x` and `y` parameters from the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter.

## Multiple blurs over specific areas (without a mask)

[image]
<sub>Blurred areas in top left, near center, and bottom.</sub>

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=50:50:20:10,avgblur=10[b0];[0:v]crop=iw:30:(iw-ow)/2:ih-oh,avgblur=10[b1];[0:v]crop=100:100:120:80,avgblur=10[b2];[0:v][b0]overlay=20:10[ovr0];[ovr0][b1]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h[ovr1];[ovr1][b2]overlay=120:80" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

## Specific area not blurred (without a mask)

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]avgblur=10[bg];[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=60:30" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

### Additional stuff

- The audio is being [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxed). No re-encoding, so it is fast and preserves the quality.
- The blurred area will have a hard edge.
- The blurred area can be moved around if you're good with [arithmetic expressions](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation), or see the [sendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) or [zmq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) filters.
- If you want to blur for a certain duration use the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) on the avgblur or the overlay.
- See the [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for other blurring filters (boxblur, dblur, gblur, sab, smartblur, unsharp, yaepblur).
- Some related questions: [How to blur a short scene in a video](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/8293/1760) and [How to add pixellate effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9107349/1109017).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. That all makes great sense.

As a side note, it also made the split filter make sense finally!

Also, could it be possible through arithmetic expressions to dynamically move the blurred box around the image? I.E. for the purpose of blurring someone's face as they move in a non-linear fashion?

Comment: Thanks again!

I'll take a crack at it.

I know that a non-linear editor would be 1000 times easier here, but I'm hoping to batch process multiple files and don't want to wait through the import/key frame/export process.

Thanks again!

Comment: does FFMPEG offer other shapes besides boxes, such as circles?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm using cmd and I want to use Example 1 but when I execute the code I get this error `Unrecognized option 'filter_complex[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,boxblur=10[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]-map [v] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sorry for such a stupid question, I'm new to all of this. how to type these 4 lines of command in 1 line? I removed the / and this is the result https://pastebin.com/ajWHzzsj and I let the / inline and this is the result (the error from my last message) https://pastebin.com/6nwNi7Y0

Comment: @Jim I noticed that my example command was missing a quote. You command should look something like this: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,boxblur=10[fg];  [0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Is it possible to use a mask image and get the blurred crop from another area in the same frame, I get this error "Input frame sizes do not match (246x60 vs 1280x720)" and of course if I make the input match it will get the same area and it will be like a normal mask  https://pastebin.com/Mpde3Rx3

Comment: @Jim I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but try switching the alphamerge and crop positions (and note that alphamerge takes two inputs–the image to apply the transparency and the mask that provides it): `[0:v][1:v]alphamerge,crop=246:60:998:98,boxblur=1[alf]`. A link to an image example may be helpful to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard let me show you this example I'm trying to hide the second sun from this frame http://i.imgur.com/iSyFdh5.png by getting part of the sky and blur it, BTW I need to use a mask http://i.imgur.com/6erW3HS.png because I have different shapes in different videos I can do the same with this code `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=245:62:999:101,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-38:39[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v -c:a -vcodec libx264 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
` but its a rectangular or square I can't do shapes with it

Comment: @LordNeckbeard can you please answer the similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1342355/alphamerge-filter-only-works-on-first-frame)?

Comment: @ZainAli Looks like I was too slow.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have observed for above case(using mask image to apply blur effect) that as you increase boxblur value then blur effect decrease, like from 1-16 it keeps on increasing and after that it start decreasing(no matter how much high value you choose), do you have any idea that why this could happen or any better suggestion to use masks to blur with correct blur intensity?

Comment: We've masked out this dog's face to protect its identity.

Comment: I'm trying to add per-frame control with `enable` but converting `avgblur=10[fg];` into `avgblur=enable='between(t,1,3)':10[fg];` did not work. Tips? *Edit:* Aha! Already solved: `avgblur=enable='between(t,1,3)':sizeX=10[fg];`

Comment: @llogan I would like to thank you very much for your answer because it was instrumental to being able to understand and become familiar with the filter graph syntax and featureset. It's indeed very powerful and makes it possible to do many cool things. However! To the original problem: The typical case of blurring of a face in video surely involves that face moving around all over the place in the frame. With AI models we can automate extracting the coordinates and size of the area to crop, but there is no way to use timeline option on the `crop` filter! How can we work around this?

Comment: I need to be able to specify a region in the frame to blur, independently for each frame of a video file. It looks certainly to be doable when using the `drawbox` filter by supplying a copy of those filters for each frame and using `enable=eq(n, $i)` but this cannot be done for `crop` even if it can be done for `avgblur` as well as `overlay`.

Answer (score 5):

For whose which didn't get how to specify a duration, here's an example

```
ffmpeg -i derpdog.mp4 -filter_complex \
 "[0:v]crop=200:100:60:30,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,60*2,60*2+10)'[fg]; \
  [0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart derpdogblur.mp4
```

The blur will appear at the `x=60`, `y=30` with a `width=200`, `height=100` from `second=120` to `second=130`

Answer (score 2):

For the case when one dislikes the sharp edge of the blurring, I made a script that layers different stages of blurring so that the edge is not sharp and it looks like this:[image: Softly_blurred_image]

Instead of this:[image: Original image]

It is a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os,stat
def blur_softly(matrix,video_in="video_to_be_blurred.mp4",video_out=""):
    if video_out == "":
        video_out = video_in[:-4] + "_blurred" + video_in[-4:]
    s0 = "ffmpeg -i " + video_in + " -filter_complex \\\n\"[0:v]null[v_int0]; \\\n"
    s1 = ''
    a = 0
    for m in matrix:
        blur = m[6]
        multiple = m[7]
        width = m[0]+blur*multiple*2
        height = m[1]+blur*multiple*2
        x_cord = m[2]-blur*multiple
        y_cord = m[3]-blur*multiple
        timein = m[4]
        timeout = m[5]
        step = m[8]
        margin = m[9]
        for i in range(blur):
            ii = multiple*i
            s0 = s0 + "[v_int0]crop="+str(width-2*ii+(margin//2)*2)+":"+str(height-2*ii+(margin//2)*2)+":"+str(x_cord+ii-margin//2)+":"+str(y_cord+ii-margin//2) + \
            ",boxblur="+str((i+1)*step)+":enable='between(t,"+str(timein)+","+str(timeout)+ \
            ")',crop="+str(width-2*ii)+ ":"+str(height-2*ii)+":"+str(margin//2)+":"+str(margin//2)+ "[blur_int" + str(i+1+a)+"]; \\\n"
            s1 = s1 + "[v_int"+ str(i+a) +"][blur_int"+str(i+a+1)+"]overlay="+str(x_cord+ii)+":"+str(y_cord+ii)+":enable='between(t,"+str(timein)+","+str(timeout)+ ")'[v_int"+str(i+a+1)+"]; \\\n"
        a += i+1
    s = s0 + s1 + "[v_int"+str(a)+"]null[with_subtitles]\" \\\n-map \"[with_subtitles]\" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -crf 17 -preset slow -y "+video_out+"\n"
    print(s)
    file_object = open('blur.sh', 'w')
    file_object.write(s)
    file_object.close()
    st = os.stat('blur.sh')
    os.chmod('blur.sh', st.st_mode | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH)
#w,h,x,y,timein,timeout,blur,multiple,step,margin
matrix = [[729,70,599,499,14.96,16.40,25,1,1,90],]
blur_softly(matrix,video_in="your_video.mp4",video_out="output_video.mp4")
```

You can change the parameters in the last and penultimate lines, the last two parametres between quatation marks are path to your video and output video (assuming they are placed in the working directory). In the penultimate line:

- the first two numbers indicate the size of the initial area to which maximum blur will be applied,
- the second two indicate the x and y coordinates thereof (top left corner),
- the third two indicate the times in seconds when the blurring should be applied,
- "25" in this example indicates that there will be 25 boxes applied on top of each other)
- the next "1" indicates that bigger boxes with less blurr should be just one pixel wider than their predecessors
- the second "1" indicates that blurring should increase by one until until maximum of 25 (from above)
- "30" indicates the margin that is taken into consideration for applying the blur, so increasing this makes the blur respect more of its surrounding. Increasing this value also solves error texted like `Invalid chroma radius value 21, must be >= 0 and <= 20`

By running it, one should get an output like the following (it gets written to a filethat can be run and printed on the output that can be copypasted and run):

```
ffmpeg -i video_to_be_blurred.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]null[v_int0]; \
[v_int0]crop=869:210:529:429,boxblur=1:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=779:120:45:45[blur_int1]; \
[v_int0]crop=867:208:530:430,boxblur=2:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=777:118:45:45[blur_int2]; \
[v_int0]crop=865:206:531:431,boxblur=3:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=775:116:45:45[blur_int3]; \
[v_int0]crop=863:204:532:432,boxblur=4:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=773:114:45:45[blur_int4]; \
[v_int0]crop=861:202:533:433,boxblur=5:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=771:112:45:45[blur_int5]; \
[v_int0]crop=859:200:534:434,boxblur=6:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=769:110:45:45[blur_int6]; \
[v_int0]crop=857:198:535:435,boxblur=7:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=767:108:45:45[blur_int7]; \
[v_int0]crop=855:196:536:436,boxblur=8:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=765:106:45:45[blur_int8]; \
[v_int0]crop=853:194:537:437,boxblur=9:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=763:104:45:45[blur_int9]; \
[v_int0]crop=851:192:538:438,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=761:102:45:45[blur_int10]; \
[v_int0]crop=849:190:539:439,boxblur=11:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=759:100:45:45[blur_int11]; \
[v_int0]crop=847:188:540:440,boxblur=12:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=757:98:45:45[blur_int12]; \
[v_int0]crop=845:186:541:441,boxblur=13:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=755:96:45:45[blur_int13]; \
[v_int0]crop=843:184:542:442,boxblur=14:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=753:94:45:45[blur_int14]; \
[v_int0]crop=841:182:543:443,boxblur=15:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=751:92:45:45[blur_int15]; \
[v_int0]crop=839:180:544:444,boxblur=16:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=749:90:45:45[blur_int16]; \
[v_int0]crop=837:178:545:445,boxblur=17:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=747:88:45:45[blur_int17]; \
[v_int0]crop=835:176:546:446,boxblur=18:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=745:86:45:45[blur_int18]; \
[v_int0]crop=833:174:547:447,boxblur=19:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=743:84:45:45[blur_int19]; \
[v_int0]crop=831:172:548:448,boxblur=20:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=741:82:45:45[blur_int20]; \
[v_int0]crop=829:170:549:449,boxblur=21:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=739:80:45:45[blur_int21]; \
[v_int0]crop=827:168:550:450,boxblur=22:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=737:78:45:45[blur_int22]; \
[v_int0]crop=825:166:551:451,boxblur=23:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=735:76:45:45[blur_int23]; \
[v_int0]crop=823:164:552:452,boxblur=24:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=733:74:45:45[blur_int24]; \
[v_int0]crop=821:162:553:453,boxblur=25:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)',crop=731:72:45:45[blur_int25]; \
[v_int0][blur_int1]overlay=574:474:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int1]; \
[v_int1][blur_int2]overlay=575:475:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int2]; \
[v_int2][blur_int3]overlay=576:476:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int3]; \
[v_int3][blur_int4]overlay=577:477:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int4]; \
[v_int4][blur_int5]overlay=578:478:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int5]; \
[v_int5][blur_int6]overlay=579:479:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int6]; \
[v_int6][blur_int7]overlay=580:480:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int7]; \
[v_int7][blur_int8]overlay=581:481:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int8]; \
[v_int8][blur_int9]overlay=582:482:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int9]; \
[v_int9][blur_int10]overlay=583:483:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int10]; \
[v_int10][blur_int11]overlay=584:484:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int11]; \
[v_int11][blur_int12]overlay=585:485:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int12]; \
[v_int12][blur_int13]overlay=586:486:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int13]; \
[v_int13][blur_int14]overlay=587:487:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int14]; \
[v_int14][blur_int15]overlay=588:488:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int15]; \
[v_int15][blur_int16]overlay=589:489:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int16]; \
[v_int16][blur_int17]overlay=590:490:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int17]; \
[v_int17][blur_int18]overlay=591:491:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int18]; \
[v_int18][blur_int19]overlay=592:492:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int19]; \
[v_int19][blur_int20]overlay=593:493:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int20]; \
[v_int20][blur_int21]overlay=594:494:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int21]; \
[v_int21][blur_int22]overlay=595:495:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int22]; \
[v_int22][blur_int23]overlay=596:496:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int23]; \
[v_int23][blur_int24]overlay=597:497:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int24]; \
[v_int24][blur_int25]overlay=598:498:enable='between(t,14.96,16.4)'[v_int25]; \
[v_int25]null[with_subtitles]" \
-map "[with_subtitles]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -crf 17 -slow preset -y video_to_be_blurred_blurred.mp4
```

Comment: If anybody knows about a easier way to achieve blury edges, I would be interested. Also, this is rather slow.

Comment: Apply a box blur to the mask before merging it.

Comment: @Gyan What do you mean? I think I am doing that already.

Comment: Anyway, I improved the code further on, I am still not sure I am doing what you recommended.

Comment: How about using an image mask, as in @llogan's answer?

Comment: @OndraŽižka Not sure how that would help - I need the bluring to kind of "blend into" the picture.

Comment: Then I guess you need to have a mask that spans the face with gray values? Not sure what kind of blending you need, but with alpha blending and an overlapping mask, I got pretty good results, except static.

Comment: Well, I am aiming for a gradual bluring, so there is no shart edge. I typically need this for texts, so rectangles work quite well. I guess a mask could be used in the same way if I needed to mask somethign notn-rectangular but that is not really mu use case. I do not see what it would do better for this use case though.

Comment: I want to give you a thumbs up! it was impressive!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking specifically about blurring a face in a video, not blurring a region using ffmpeg:

There's the [Deface](https://github.com/ORB-HD/deface) project which splits video into frames, detects faces using OpenCV and a trained neural network, and applies a blur to those places.

[image: Blurred faces sample image]

The results are so-so, it is not usable for any serious anonymization where it really matters, because there are a lot of false negatives. But there is a clearly visible unobstructed face not at the edge of the video, it does the job.

A few simple improvements of Deface could fix the false negatives/positives, see the project's tickets. So if you happen to be a programmer, I encourage you to fork and implement those :)