# Alphamerge filter only works on first frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg, alpha-channel

I am trying to implement blur filter over specific non rectangle object, I have mask and sample video but the issue is that alphamerge result of first frame of video is applied to the whole video(Like you overlayed a static image over the whole length of video)
I used the following command

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample_video.mp4 -i masked_image.png -filter_complex 
"[0:v][1:v]alphamerge,boxblur=16[alf];[0:v][alf]overlay[v]" -map [v] -map 0:a -c:a copy -preset ultrafast test.mp4
```

[sample_video.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uO-1w8G0xUWXbDirfZjtSi7OlPBrHaY5) [masked_image.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zLu5ihm3hVClq2tIi615PrjsrjI7MpJD)

**UPDATE:**
Your solution is working quite well but now blur intensity value is not effecting blur intensity

[Mask Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xtp_gqsWiBVfvklvL2atgGw7ryYg6m2l)

[Sample Image](https://drive.google.com/openid=1anAPXOEDDAvTseqygZRi7oRC9seA6tUT)

[Result with boxblur=10](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_NszGONk1DwHsGJae2cwKIoKVQNePZ3y)

[Result with boxblur=30](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KOJEGNb7fEo9_SNMAKROI4OY9TqrkVFd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mask is a single image so it won't track the subject, but I assume your issue is that the overlay pixels are static. You'll need to loop the mask since alphamerge terminates with the shortest input, and the overlay will repeat the last frame of the secondary input.

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample_video.mp4 -loop 1 -i masked_image.png ...
```

Comment: I have observed for above case(using mask image to apply blur effect) that as you increase boxblur value then blur effect decrease, like from 1-16 it keeps on increasing and after that it start decreasing(no matter how much high value you choose), do you have any idea that why this could happen or any better suggestion to use masks to blur?

Comment: Can you post example pics?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Change `boxblur=16` to `boxblur=16:ap=0`. We don't want to blur the alpha plane.